# Can JavaScript be considered a class-based language?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Before ES6, JavaScript had no way to create classes (I know it has its own way of creating them which are constructors....) and it is a prototype-based language.

Now, after adding class declarations and new inheritance ways can it be considered a class-based language like Java and C++?

Comment: You mean an object-oriented language?

Comment: This definitely depends on what "class-based" means. ES6 class syntax still creates objects using prototypal inheritance.

Comment: JavaScript is already an object-oriented language but not class-based as the other languages!

Comment: Javascript is not and cannot be a class-based language. Classes are syntactic sugar as a result of pressure from people coming from a class based programming language.

Comment: ES6 classes are effectively just syntactic sugar for the underlying prototypal underpinnings of ES<6.

Comment: which means javascript isn't - and wouldn't be - a class based?

Comment: "*…and new inheritance ways*" such as? You've answered your own question: "*ES6 class syntax still creates objects using prototypal inheritance.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is an object oriented language and always has been.

The new ES6 class syntax merely provides a prettier way to declare something that you could already do in the language before ES6 (you just had to manually configure somethings that are now done for you).

The new ES6 class syntax still uses the prototype in exactly the same way that objects in ES5 and before did.  So, there is really nothing new under the covers.  ES6 codifies into actual language syntax something that most developers were already doing (defining objects, inheriting from other object definitions, etc...).

So, the ES6 class syntax really just makes things more convenient for the developer.  It does not fundamentally change what Javascript is capable of or how it works.

> Before ES6, javascript had no way to create classes (I know it has ts own way of creating them which are constructors....) and it is a prototype-based language.

This statement is a bit misguided.  ES6 still works the same way ES5 did.  It still uses the prototype.  Object definitions from the `class` keyword are created the same way they were in ES5 (using the prototype).  We just now have a built-in syntax rather than declaring a constructor manually and then adding methods to the prototype.  So, there are syntax improvements, but not fundamental changes in how it works once the object is declared.

> Now, after adding class declarations and new inheritance ways can it be considered a class-based language like Java and C++?

Not really.  It's still a prototype-based language and even the `class` declaration just ends up building a prototype.  I would say Javascript is very object-oriented (always has been).  I would not attempt to compare it to Java and C++ in this regard because it's kind of like comparing apples and oranges.  They go about things differently and there's no absolute measure of "more" or "less" class-based that is objective or useful.

I would recommend spending time on the strengths and weaknesses of different languages you know or are considering learning so you understand what they can best be used for and don't spend any time trying to figure out which is "more" or "better" than the other.  They are very different and can all be used to do a wide variety of things.  Some are better tools in the toolkit for some things vs. others based on their individual strengths.